# Asp.Net MVC KendoUI grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RTM.WEB.MVC.ViewModels.SortingViewModel.ProductViewModel>()
.Name("ProductsGrid").HtmlAttributes("height:430")
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(p => p.IsSelected).Width(50).Title("");
columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
columns.Bound(p => p.Price).Format("{0:C}");
columns.Bound(p => p.GroupName);
// columns.Bound(p => p.MeasurementId);
// columns.Bound(p => p.BarcodeValue);
columns.Command(comand =>
{
comand.Custom("Edit").Click("ViewEdit");
comand.Destroy();

}).Title("Commands").Width(180);

})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

.Ajax()
.PageSize(10)
//.Events(events=>events.Sync("addGroupData"))
.ServerOperation(true)
.Batch(true)

.Events(events =>
{
events.Error("errorHandler");
events.Sync("addDataToResponce");
})
.Model(model =>
{
model.Id(p => p.ProductId);
model.Field(p => p.ProductId).Editable(false);
})

//                                      .Aggregates(aggregates =>
//{
//    //aggregates.Add(p => p.ProductId);
//    //aggregates.Add(p => p.ProductName);
//    aggregates.Add(p => p.Price).Sum();
//})


.Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.GroupName))

.Create(create => create.Action("Products_Create", "Sorting"))
.Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Sorting"))
.Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "Sorting"))
.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Products_Destroy", "Sorting"))
)
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
toolbar.Template(@<text>
<div >
<a class="k-button" onclick="AddProduct()">Add New Product</a>
@item.SaveButton()
<a class="k-button" onclick="NewGroup()">NewGroup</a>
<a class="k-button" onclick="UnGroup()">UnGroup</a>
<label>Show products by warehouse:</label>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("warehouses")
.OptionLabel("All")
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("WarehouseId")
.AutoBind(false)
// .Events(e => e.Change("warehousesChange"))
.DataSource(ds =>
{
ds.Read("Products_Warehouses", "Sorting");

})
)
</div>
</text>);

})
.Events(events =>
{
events.DataBound("dataBound");
})
.Pageable(page => page.PageSizes(true).Numeric(false).Refresh(true).Input(true))
//.Navigatable()
.Selectable()
.ColumnMenu()
.Filterable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
)
public JsonResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
int allcount=0;
List<ProductModel> products= DataManager.ProductRepository.GetAllProducts(request.Page, request.PageSize,ref allcount);
List<ProductViewModel> productViewModels=new List<ProductViewModel>();
foreach (var product in products)
{
productViewModels.Add(ConvertProductViewModel(product));
}
if (request.Sorts.Count != 0)
{
string member = request.Sorts.First().Member;
string sorttype = request.Sorts.First().SortDirection.ToString();
switch (member)
{
case "IsSelected":
if (sorttype == "Ascending")
{
productViewModels = productViewModels.OrderBy(p => p.IsSelected).ToList();
}
if (sorttype == "Descending")
{
productViewModels = productViewModels.OrderByDescending(p => p.IsSelected).ToList();
}
break;
case "ProductName":
if (sorttype == "Ascending")
{
productViewModels = productViewModels.OrderBy(p => p.ProductName).ToList();
}
if (sorttype == "Descending")
{
productViewModels = productViewModels.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductName).ToList();
}
break;
case "Price":
if (sorttype == "Ascending")
{
productViewModels = productViewModels.OrderBy(p => p.Price).ToList();
}
if (sorttype == "Descending")
{
productViewModels = productViewModels.OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).ToList();
}
break;
}

}


var result = new DataSourceResult()
{
Data = productViewModels,
Total = allcount,
AggregateResults = null,
Errors = null,
};
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my code.When i return data from action server paging doesn't work.
I want do server paging kendo ui group grid, but response data type undefined.I need working example for group grid.It works in basic grid  but don't work for group grid.

Answer (score 2):

You should just need to update the controller method. As the sorting you are doing seems quite basic, you can use the supplied Kendo method `ToDataSourceResult(DataSourceRequest request)`.

Add the following to your using section in the Controller:

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
```

Then simply return:

```
 return Json(productViewModels 
     .ToDataSourceResult(request, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
```

This should take care of any filtering, sorting, grouping, and paging for you.

You might also want to take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org) to more easily map objects from `Product` to `ProductViewModel`.

Comment: If you change the code `DataManager.ProductRepository.GetAllProducts(request.Page, request.PageSize,ref allcount);` to just return all objects, the `ToDataSourceResult` method will take care of the paging and total for you. If you want to pass the paging back to the database then I would suggest looking at AutoMapper, as this would let you do `...ProductRepository.GetAllProducts().Select(AutoMapper.Map<ProductViewModel>).ToDataSourceResult(...)`.

Comment: I don't want get all data from DB,because if data is too much it works very slow.